# Pony throws NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pony

I have this spec:

```
describe EmailerHelper do
  describe "send email" do
    include EmailerHelper
    include Pony::TestHelpers
    before { sendUBEmail('nobody@nowhere.net','Test Subject','Test Body') }
    it "Pony has received the email" do
      current_email.address.should == "noobody@nowhere.net"
    end
  end
end
```

this is the sendUBEmail currently:

```
module EmailerHelper
  def sendUBEmail(receiver,subject,body)
    if Rails.env != 'production'
      #TODO - make test email an environment variable
      Pony.mail(:to => 'p***@p***.net', :subject => subject, :body => body)
    else
      Pony.mail(:to => receiver, :subject => subject, :html_body => body)
    end
  end
end
```

When I run this spec I get this error

```
  1) EmailerHelper send email Pony has received the email
     Failure/Error: before { sendUBEmail('nobody@nowhere.net','Test Subject','Test Body') }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `build_tmail' for Pony:Module
     # ./app/helpers/emailer_helper.rb:5:in `sendUBEmail'
     # ./spec/helpers/emailer_helper_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Where is this 'build_tmail'? It's not in the Pony module and why is the method not found.

Answer (score 1):

I had a old version of Pony-Test gumming up the works, revised the Gemfile to point to the latest, fixed.